# Base class for implementing IComparable<T>

Tags: c#

If I create a class that implements `IComparable<T>`, I must implement `CompareTo<T>`. It is also recommended that I implement `IEquatable<T>` and the non-generic `IComparable`. If I do all that, I am required or encouraged to:

- Override `GetHashCode()`
- Implement `CompareTo(Object)`
- Override `Equals(Object)`
- Implement `Operator ==(T, T)`
- Implement `Operator !=(T, T)`
- Implement `Operator >(T, T)`
- Implement `Operator <(T, T)`
- Implement `Operator >=(T, T)`
- Implement `Operator <=(T, T)`

That's 9 additional methods, most of which depend on the logic that compares two instances of the class. Rather than having to implement all those methods in any class that implements `IComparable<T>`, I decided to create a base class that implements `IComparable<T>` and the other recommended interfaces (similar to the way Microsoft provides `Comparer` as a base class for implementations of `IComparer<T>`)

It doesn't make sense to compare instances of two different classes that each inherit from the base class. preventing that was the main reason for making the class generic (although it makes coding a derived class a little more complicate).

I would like to ask for a review of the code for the base class. Am I missing something? Can it be simplified? Is this a bad idea?

Here is the base class

```
public abstract class Comparable<T> : IComparable, IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T> where T: Comparable<T> {
    public abstract override int GetHashCode();

    public abstract int CompareTo(T other);

    public int CompareTo(object obj) {
        T other = obj as T;
        if (other == null && obj != null) {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Objects of type {typeof(T).Name} can only be compared to objects of the same type", nameof(obj));
        }
        return CompareTo(other);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        return CompareTo(obj) == 0;
    }

    new public bool Equals(T other) {
        return CompareTo(other) == 0;
    }

    private static int Compare(Comparable<T> comp1, Comparable<T> comp2) {
        if (comp1 == null) {
            return ((comp2 == null) ? 0 : -1);
        }
        return comp1.CompareTo(comp2);
    }

    public static bool operator == (Comparable<T> comp1, Comparable<T> comp2) {
        return Compare(comp1, comp2) == 0;
    }

    public static bool operator != (Comparable<T> comp1, Comparable<T> comp2) {
        return Compare(comp1, comp2) != 0;
    }

    public static bool operator > (Comparable<T> comp1, Comparable<T> comp2) {
        return Compare(comp1, comp2) > 0;
    }

    public static bool operator < (Comparable<T> comp1, Comparable<T> comp2) {
        return Compare(comp1, comp2) < 0;
    }

    public static bool operator >= (Comparable<T> comp1, Comparable<T> comp2) {
        return Compare(comp1, comp2) >= 0;
    }

    public static bool operator <= (Comparable<T> comp1, Comparable<T> comp2) {
        return Compare(comp1, comp2) <= 0;
    }
}
```

Below is a minimal implementation of the base class.

```
public class SeasonCompare : Comparable<SeasonCompare> {
    public int Number {get; set;}

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return Number;
    }

    public override int CompareTo(SeasonCompare other) {
        if (other == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        return Number.CompareTo(other.Number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It is also recommended that I implement ... the non-generic `IComparable`.

I don't see that recommendation in [the current doc for IComparable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=netframework-4.7.2). I would recommend against it: having the non-generic method turns compile-time errors into runtime errors, which are more expensive to find and fix.

---

> ```
>       private static int Compare(Comparable<T> comp1, Comparable<T> comp2) {
>           if (comp1 == null) {
>               return ((comp2 == null) ? 0 : -1);
>           }
>           return comp1.CompareTo(comp2);
>       }
> ```

For consistency, this requires that subclasses guarantee that `CompareTo(null)` returns a positive value, but that requirement isn't documented.

Perhaps a better solution would be:

```
        private static int Compare(Comparable<T> comp1, Comparable<T> comp2) {
            if (comp1 == null) {
                return comp2 == null ? 0 : 0.CompareTo(comp2.CompareTo(comp1));
            }
            return comp1.CompareTo(comp2);
        }
```

That way the only requirement is that `CompareTo(null)` be consistent.

There may be a more elegant way of inverting the sense of a comparison, but that's the easiest one I can think of which doesn't fail on corner cases.

Comment: Thanks @petertaylor. I suppose I just assumed that `CompareTo(null)` should return a positive value. I'll take your advice and change the `Compare` method.

Comment: On the subject of implementing IComparable, it is true that this is not suggested in the documentation. I got the recommendation from a  Stack Overflow answer (that I now can't find) that argued for implementing IComparable in order to avoid problems when sorting an ArrayList containing objects of the class. If I don't implement IComparable, I get an InvalidOperationException when sorting an ArrayList containing objects of my class. I wouldn't use an ArrayList myself, but I suppose I should allow for people who would. Do you still recommend against implementing IComparable?

Comment: @Blackwood, I see it as a tradeoff between a little pain for people who chose runtime checks over compile-time checks by not upgrading to Net Framework 2.0 vs a little pain for everyone else. As far as I'm concerned, let the `ArrayList` users call a `Sort` overload which takes an `IComparer`.

Comment: That makes sense (and simplifies my code). Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

#### Stack Overflow Exception

You did not test your code appropriately because it throws the `StackOverflowException` for

```
(x == y)
```

This is the rare case when this happens and is triggered by these two methods.

> ```
> public static bool operator ==(Comparable<T> comp1, Comparable<T> comp2)
> {
>   return Compare(comp1, comp2) == 0;
> }
> ```

This calls the `Compare` method which in turn calls `comp1 == null` which means that `Compare` is called... and so on...

> ```
> private static int Compare(Comparable<T> comp1, Comparable<T> comp2)
> {
>   if (comp1 == null)
>   {
>       return ((comp2 == null) ? 0 : -1);
>   }
>   return comp1.CompareTo(comp2);
> }
> ```

When implementing comparers or equalities you should **always** use `object.ReferenceEquals` for checking arguments against `null` and **never** `== null`.

---

You should also use standard names for parameters like `x` & `y` or `left` & `right` and not `comp1` and `comp2`.

Comment: How embarrassing. I had not tested the equality operator since I converted the code from VB.Net (where `comp1 Is Nothing` does not cause the error) to C#. I apologize.

Comment: @Blackwood yeah, VB.NET is full of surprises by doing things differently than the rest of the world ;-)